# Авторизация или защита от угона сессионного токена

Tags: php, авторизация, безопасность

шифрую сессионный идентификатор который расположен в куках следующим образом: `IP + UserAgent` ...

`IP` отпадает, так как у пользователей могут быть динамические `IP`, но так же отпадает и безопасность(с IP она была хоть какая-то)

Скажите, можно как-то более надежно организовать? Есть ли другие алгоритмы?

Comment: ваш вопрос явно требует доработки

Comment: Зачем шифровать токен? И если уж шифровать, то как: симметричными или асимметричными шифрами?

Comment: @cmd, HTTPS + HSTS ( https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSTS ) + куки HttpOnly + своевременно обновляемый антивирус и правильно настроенный firewall на стороне пользователя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как написали в комментах - HttpOnly будет прекрасным решением, исключающим XSS. Простой и надежный флаг. Если же задача в том, чтобы куки не работали будучи перехваченными, можно использовать юзер агент, разрешение экрана и информацию об ОС. Часто делают привязку к региону, которому принадлежит IP